# Yii2 model to exclude related records

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two related tables, `posts` and `hidden_posts`, where `posts`.`id` corresponds to `hidden_posts`.`post_id`.

In my `posts` model I have this relation to return a record if the post should be hidden:

```
  public function getHiddenPosts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(HiddenPost::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Now I need to return all posts that are NOT hidden. So I am looking for the equivalent of this pseudo code:

`return $this->hasNone(HiddenPost::className(), ['post_id' => 'id'])->all();`

Which is saying, "show me all posts that are not in the hidden_posts table".

So does this use an outer join query or is there a statement that I can't find do do this in one line?

Comment: seems you need  a inner join  instead of a left join  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way. Get all posts that are not listed in Hidden table:

```
$posts = Post::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['not in', 
        'post.id',
        HiddenPost::find()
           ->select(['hidden_post.post_id'])
    ->all();
```

In any case, it is best to proceed from the raw SQL statement. Write a statement that satisfies your results and transfer it to ActiveRecord query.

Answer (score 0):

You could  retrive the Post items using  an inner join

```
$posts = Post::find()
->select('post.*')
->innerJoin('hidden_post', '`post`.`id` = `hidden_post`.`post_id`')
->all();
```

for not hidden then  use left join and check for null result of related  table

```
 $posts = Post::find()
->select('post.*')
->leftJoin('hidden_post', '`post`.`id` = `hidden_post`.`post_id`')
->where('ISNULL(`hidden_post`.console_id)')
->all();
```

Comment: This will find the posts that **are** hidden. The question was about posts that **are not** hidden. You would have to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and add `hidden_post.post_id IS NULL` to `WHERE` part if you wanted to use join.

Comment: @MichalHynčica  thank you, I understood the opposite ..answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

Post items could be retrieved using  an inner join

```
$res = Post::find()
->select('post.*')
->innerJoin('hdn_post', '`post`.`id` = `hdn_post`.`post_id`')
->all();
```

Comment: This gets all posts that are in Hidden table. I need all posts that are NOT in hidden table.

Answer (score 0):

It could be good practice using yii2 owned function instead of adding queries inside the model such as using select queries in your model.

Instead you can use ORM functions in yii2 has already done by gii inner functions created for to make u=your work easy.

Add   `* @property YourModel $hidden_post`
and inside this model add you post_id such as ( `* @property integer $post_id` ) to create relation.

```
public function getHiddenPosts($hidden_post) {
    return $this->find()->joinWith('hidden_post')
        ->where(['hidden_post' => $hidden_post])
        ->all();
}
```